# How to change tableview data with button press on a different view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am having a bit of trouble getting a button pressed on a ViewController to load a specific lot of information in an array for displaying on a UITableViewController.

I know you can do it with detecting the segue but I have tried this without - I had success. I read somewhere else how I can use tags on the button to identify it and I tried to use this but it only displays one set of data no matter what button I have pressed. I've tried swapping a lot of things around to try and get it to work but to no avail. I have a ViewController with the buttons on it, a TableViewController to display the arrays and a CellViewController to display the better description of the tableview info.

My code is pretty 'all over the shop' at the moment. I haven't included the Cell View controllers as I don't think they have that much relevance with what I want to do at this stage.The buttonviewcontroller is just a normal UIViewController and both buttons are linked as 'Button1'class in the storyboard. They have been given tags 0 and 1 which I believe is in under the 'view' subheading in the storyboard. Please alert me if this is wrong and I am missing something really obvious but that was the only place I could find 'tag'.

Honestly I don't know exactly what I'm doing in xcode as I'm not very familiar with it but seem to understanding parts of it. However, I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong at the moment.

Code:

ButtonViewController.M (this is where the buttons are)

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "tableViewController.h"
    #import "TableCell.h"

    @interface ButtonViewController : UIViewController

    -(IBAction) button_Clicked:(id)sender;


    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Button1;

    @end
```

ButtonViewController.m

```
   #import "ButtonViewController.h"
   #import "tableViewController.h"
   #import "TableCell.h"

   @interface ButtonViewController ()

   @end


   @implementation ButtonViewController

   -(IBAction) button_Clicked:(id)sender
{

//something here that is going wrong

tableViewController *tableVC = [[tableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"tableViewController" bundle:nil];

    if(_Button1.tag==0)
    {
    tableVC.buttonSelected = 0;
    }

    else if(_Button1.tag==1)
    {
    tableVC.buttonSelected = 1;
    }



[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES];
    [tableVC.tableView reloadData];

@end
```

tableViewController.h

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface tableViewController : UITableViewController

    @property (nonatomic, assign) int buttonSelected;

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Title;
     //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Title;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Description;
     //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Description;
    //Not sure if Mutable or normal array
    @end
```

tableViewController.m

```
    #import "tableViewController.h"
    #import "TableCell.h"
    #import "DetailViewController.h"
    #import "ButtonViewController.h"

    @interface tableViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation tableViewController

       - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
          {
           self = [super initWithStyle:style];
             if (self) {
             // Custom initialization
             }
           return self;
          }
    - (void)viewDidLoad
     {

    [super viewDidLoad];

      if(_buttonSelected == 0)
    {
        _Title = @[@"Hamstring Muscle Tear",@"Lower Back Pain"];
        _Description = @[@"Blahahaha", @"blahahaha2",@"blalalala3"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];          
    }

    else if (_buttonSelected == 1)
    {
        _Title = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"];
        _Description = @[@"dededdededde", @"deddedede2",@"blalalala3"];
          [self.tableView reloadData];
    }



     #pragma mark - Table view data source
     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {

      // Return the number of sections.
      return 1;
        } 

       - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
      {

       // Return the number of rows in the section.
       return _Title.count;
       }

       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...

         int row = [indexPath row];

         cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
          cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];

         return cell;
         }
       -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

       if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

       int row = [myIndexPath row];
       detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_Description[row]];
       }

        }
      @end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to doing same.

1. Implement delegate method and call it on event.
2. You can fire NSPostNotification event from one controller to another controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change the data, then post an `NSNotification` that it changed.

The table view data source observes the notification and calls `[tableView reloadData]`

You can find details how to do this in apple's sample code.